# Node.js Equivalent for htmlspecialchars in php

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, ejs

i'm actually getting data from my mysql database in which there is text with accents like

> " é è à â ê... "

but when i render it to my ejs file with node.js it shows me

> "h�lo" for "hélo"

.
The problem is easyli solver with php and the function `htmlspecialchars(str);` 
is there any equivalent for this function in Node ?

Thank you

Comment: PHP's `htmlspecialchars` wouldn't help there. You'd need `htmlentities`. (And it would only fix things if the problem was between PHP and the browser, it wouldn't help if the problem was between PHP and MySQL or if the data was put into the DB in a broken state in the first place).

Comment: You really should solve this by normalising your character encodings (and using UTF-8 everywhere).

Comment: Try this one: `Buffer.from(str).toString('utf8')`. But I think Your serverside web app does not return utf-8 encoding header, with `express` framework try to call: `res.charset = 'utf-8';` before calling `res.render()`  otherwise I suspect that data stored with `utf-8` encoding in table column that has `latin1` encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you set your encoding correctly (on the html page and in the database or convert before inserting/after selecting) you shouldn't need to convert special chars to HTML entities to avoid the described behaviour. `htmlspecialchars()` should be used to prevent people from posting HTML (converting `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;`).

If you still need to escape HTML special characters, take a look at this NPM package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities

Use it like this :

```
const Entities = require('html-entities').AllHtmlEntities;
const entities = new Entities();

console.log(entities.encode("éèàâê");
```

will output

```
&eacute;&egrave;&agrave;&acirc;&ecirc;
```

Comment: The encoding is good actually ( UTF8 on my html ) and (utf8bin_unicode_ci in the database)  I tried to use the library you sent me and it didn't work, any idea ?

Comment: If you don't see the same characters in your database and in your HTML page, then somewhere between the database and the HTML page it's being re-encoded differently. If you give more info on your code you might get some help there. As for `htmlspecialchars`, @Quentin was right, what you need is a `htmlentities()` function. Check the edited answer

Comment: you mean i can do : myTitle[i] = entities.encode(results[i].title) and then do res.render('mypage' , { Titile : myTitle}); And it will display it correctly ?

Comment: ps: i re encoded all my database with utf8_unicode_ci which is slow but reads accents ( mysql documentation)

Comment: I was about to suggest that !